# 1142 Error using PDO in spite of using mysql_native_password

Tags: php, python, pdo

This question was marked earlier as a duplicate even though I had already implemented the most-searched solutions. I modified the MySql user to use native passwords using the following line (which did not fix my connection issue):

```
ALTER USER user_insert_ IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password123';
```

This code was a solution referenced here: [phpMyAdmin on MySQL 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49948350/phpmyadmin-on-mysql-8-0) (Also the solution from which this thread is marked as a duplicate)

## 1142 SELECT command denied to user

I am using MySQL 8.0 and php 7.3.0

I have granted full permissions for 'user_insert_'@'127.0.0.1', and am able to run the following SELECT statement fine from pymysql and MySQL Workbench, but not through PDO in php:

```
"SELECT * FROM worker_status"
```

The error I receive is:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'user_insert_'@'localhost' for table 'worker_status' in C:\xampp\htdocs\hud\test_api_2\objects\activity.php:33

I expected to receive a single row response.

Here's the relevant code :

```
class Database{

private $host = "127.0.0.1";
private $db_name = "hud";
private $username = "user_insert_";
private $password = "password123";
private $charset = 'utf8mb4';
private $dsn = "";
public $conn;

public function getConnection(){
  $this->conn = null;

    $this->dsn = "mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->db_name;charset=$this->charset";
    print($this->dsn);
    $this->options = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];

    try {
     $this->conn = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->username, $this->password, $this->options);
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
         throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
    }


    return $this->conn;
}


    public function __construct($db){
    $this->conn = $db;
}

function read(){

    $query = "SELECT * FROM worker_status";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch();

    return $stmt;
}
```

Also, when trying to access phpmyadmin at "", I get a [red](https://imgur.com/GLMbtf5) error message referencing that caching_sha2_password is not enabled for broswer access.

I've checked:

- show grants for 'user_insert_'@'127.0.0.1'; -- Which shows that all permissions are granted for that user.
- There aren't any exceptions generated when the database connection starts.
- The correct database and table is being connected to.
- That my PDO syntax matches the documentation.
- The user is already connecting using mysql_native_password ( Reference: [phpMyAdmin on MySQL 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49948350/phpmyadmin-on-mysql-8-0))

This seemed to me like a pretty vanilla case. Why am I getting a 1142 SELECT permission error exclusively with php PDO?

Comment: Do you get an error when you try connecting to the DB? What I mean is, comment out your `read()` function and just run the `getConnection()` and see if it tosses you an error. If it does then try using `root` to try and connect to DB, if you can connect to the DB with `root` then it means the account you were trying to use to connect to before was not given the proper permissions.

Comment: @JeanPaul98 No I don't get an error by just running getConnection, unless I run as root. (Then I get the error I referenced: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49948350/phpmyadmin-on-mysql-8-0 which relates to the `mysql_native_password` symptom that I get from using mysql 8.0)

Comment: @JeanPaul98 When I connect as root I get the expected response `Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client`

Comment: @JeanPaul98 When I connect as a user which has `mysql_native_password` enabled, then I get the unexpected response `Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'user_insert_'@'localhost' for table 'worker_status' `

Comment: And this all comes as a surprise because full permissions are granted to user_insert_ for that table (and I've tried host: localhost, and 127.0.0.1)

Comment: This looks like it could take a while to fix and I would rather not continue the discussion on SO unless it leads to a fix, message me here https://discord.gg/fWgac (link expires in an hour)

Comment: I got no clue what that means...?

Comment: It means I had to go to class, and I couldn't click on your link that would expire in an hour.

Comment: https://discord.gg/39jnPp