# How Can Run Phpmyadmin, Mysql and Apache Tomcat with Docker-Compose File?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run java web app. Thus, I must setup MySQL, phpmyadmin and Apache Tomcat for accessing website. I want to use the docker and its `docker-compose` application to make installation easier (If I may learn).

I could not set `mysql` and `phpmyadmin` applications to work together. If I can get past this first step, I will try to install `tomcat`.

This is my codes which is used(`docker-compose.yml`)

```
version: '2'
services:
    db:
        image: mysql
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: myDb
            MYSQL_USER: admin
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 12345
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        ports:
        - "8080:80"
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: admin
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 12345
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        depends_on: 
            - db
        links:
            - db
```

I open the above codes with `docker-compose up` in the command line application.

I'm going to `http://localhost:8080/` page, I'm typing `admin` for Username, `12345` for password.

The errors I get are:

```
Cannot log in to MySQL server
mysqli_real_connect (): The server requested authentication method
mysqli_real_connect (): (HY000 / 2054): The server requested authentication method
```

How can I install the applications (`mysql`, `phpmyadmin`, `tomcat`) with `docker-compose`?

Comment: could you try login/access to `db` container from `php-admin` container with bash?

Comment: I tried to some codes but I did not achieve. I think, my codes are wrong. Can you suggest a code? How can I do that?

Comment: @PPShein I entered the bash screen from the docker using this code `docker exec -it desktop_db_1 /bin/bash` and I tried to connect inside with this code `mysql -uroot -proot` or `mysql -uadmin -p12345` and I accessed with successfully but I still can not access at `http://localhost:8080/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Currently phpmyadmin and MySQL can work together. It is solved.**

PLAN A:
This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    db:
        container_name: db
        image: mysql
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: myDb
            MYSQL_USER: admin
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 12345
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    phpmyadmin:
        depends_on: 
            - db
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: admin
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 12345
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            PMA_HOST: db
```

Now, you can go into `MySQL` via `phpmyadmin` at `http://localhost:8080`

**It can also be solved by this method.**

PLAN B: This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    db:
        container_name: db
        image: mysql
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: myDb
            MYSQL_USER: admin
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 12345
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    phpmyadmin:
        depends_on: 
            - db
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: admin
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 12345
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            PMA_HOST: db
```

Command line's commands:

```
$ docker stop phpmyadmin
$ docker exec -it db bash
$ mysql -u root -proot
$ ALTER USER root IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';
$ exit
$ exit
$ docker start phpmyadmin
```

Now, you can go into `MySQL` via `phpmyadmin` at `http://localhost:8080`

Reference: [phpMyAdmin on MySQL 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49948350/phpmyadmin-on-mysql-8-0/50437307#50437307)

Comment: No tomcat in this question... but plan A and plan B are working both. very educational exercise for beginners docker.

Answer (score 0):

```
version: '3.1'
    services:
      db:
        image: mysql
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        restart: always
        ports:
          - 3307:3306
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
      phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        ports:
          - 8080:80
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
        links:
          - db
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be nice if you could include a description on what you have changed, and how you think it answers the question.